# What is the best approch while returning API response to web/Android/iOS?

Tags: php, android, ios, api, response

**Use case** : Posts filter items.

**Summary**  : Posts will be filter by tags and category wise.

In this case i am returning filter items via a endpoint. The response are following.

**Issue**    : Android/iOS developer are disagree with this response. Because of if i return KEY(tags/categories) wise response they 
           need to create 2 extra CLASS and that is cost with static binding. Also for future if i add another filter item like(rating-wise) they need to do again.

**My response :**

```
{
    "status" : true,
    "code"   : 200,
    "data"   : {
        "tags" : {
            "filterTitle" : "Search By TAGS",
            "lists"       : [
                {
                    "tagId" : 1,
                    "tagName" : "AWS"
                },
                {
                    "tagId" : 2,
                    "tagName" : "PHP"
                },
                {
                    "tagId" : 3,
                    "tagName" : "ASP"
                }
            ]
        },
        "categories" : {
            "filterTitle" : "Search By Category",
            "lists"       : [
                {
                    "catId"   : 10,
                    "catName" : "Web Services"
                },
                {
                    "catId"   : 20,
                    "catName" : "Programming"
                },
                {
                    "catId"   : 30,
                    "catName" : "Tools"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "message" : "successfull"
}
```

**Android/iOS developer required :**

```
{
    "status" : true,
    "code"   : 200,
    "data"   : [
        {
            "filterTitle" : "Search By TAGS",
            "lists"       : [
                {
                    "tagId" : 1,
                    "tagName" : "AWS"
                },
                {
                    "tagId" : 2,
                    "tagName" : "PHP"
                },
                {
                    "tagId" : 3,
                    "tagName" : "ASP"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "filterTitle" : "Search By Category",
            "lists"       : [
                {
                    "catId"   : 10,
                    "catName" : "Web Services"
                },
                {
                    "catId"   : 20,
                    "catName" : "Programming"
                },
                {
                    "catId"   : 30,
                    "catName" : "Tools"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "message" : "successfull"
}
```

Comment: you should add all filter items if thats not required at this time you should pass null for "rating wise" as you said the app developer add model classess for json so in future if you send result by rating they don't need to create clas or that they already have one

Answer (score 0):

Why not design the API to do the filtering. I know that data is not too much so you won't want to do it, but if that's the case any of the above implementation is fine, and yes they are correct they will need extra classes for each new filter type.

Comment: I know both of this. The issue is when i transform this as android/iOS developer needed i need to prepare the array of object and remove model name and it will be a cost of HTTP call response.